# DFS implementation to find route between two tree nodes

Tags: python, tree, depth-first-search, path-finding

```
class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def getDFSpath(root,goal,stack):
    stack.append(root.val)
    if root.left is None and root.right is None and root.val != goal:
        stack.pop()
        return []
    elif root.val == goal:
        return stack
    else:
        leftstack = getDFSpath(root.left,goal,stack)
        rightstack = getDFSpath(root.right,goal,stack)
        if len(leftstack) == 0 and len(rightstack) > 0:
            return rightstack
        elif len(rightstack) == 0 and len(leftstack) > 0:
            return leftstack
        else:
            return []

one = TreeNode(1)
two =TreeNode(2)
three =TreeNode(3)
four = TreeNode(4)
five =TreeNode(5)
six =TreeNode(6)
seven =TreeNode(7)
eight = TreeNode(8)
nine =TreeNode(9)
ten = TreeNode(10)
eleven = TreeNode(11)

one.left = two
one.right = three
two.left = four
two.right = five
three.left = six
three.right = seven
four.left = ten
four.right = eleven
five.left = nine
five.right = eight
mystack = getDFSpath(one,11,[])
print(mystack)
```

I am not sure what is wrong with this implementation. I am trying to find a route between node one and goal node with value 11. The correct ans should be [1,2,4,11]. However it is returning: [1, 2, 4, 11, 5, 3]

Answer (score 0):

Lets look closer at following lines of code:

```
leftstack = getDFSpath(root.left,goal,stack)
rightstack = getDFSpath(root.right,goal,stack)
```

Here you call DFS for both left and right node and pass same `stack` variable. For example, calling DFS for left node finds a path (Simple example - route from 1 to 2). After that you call DFS for right node (3). As longer you use same stack` variable calling DFS for right node will modify it. Look at following line:

```
if root.left is None and root.right is None and root.val != goal:
```

For node 3 it's not true, so it won't remove 3 from stack! And you will get `[1, 2, 3]` as a result. Also you don't handle a case when your node has only left or only right child. Fixed code with my comments:

```
def getDFSpath(root, goal, stack):
    stack.append(root.val)
    if root.val == goal:
        return stack
    else:
        leftstack = getDFSpath(root.left, goal, stack[:]) if root.left is not None else []  # if left node is missing skip it
        rightstack = getDFSpath(root.right, goal, stack[:]) if root.right is not None else []  # if right node is missing skip it
        if len(leftstack) == 0 and len(rightstack) > 0:
            return rightstack
        elif len(rightstack) == 0 and len(leftstack) > 0:
            return leftstack
        else:
            stack.pop()  # we didn't find path, remove current node from stack
            return []
```

Output:

> [1, 2, 4, 11]